# Cannot use int post-decrement in function call

Tags: c++, recursion, exponential

I made a recursive exponential function and originally called the recursive function as **return num * power(num, exp--)**, however I had to change it to **exp-1** because the first method broke the program. Why do I have to use **exp-1**?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int power(int num, int exp);

int main()
{
    cout << power(5, 3) << endl;

    return 0;
}

int power(int num, int exp)
{
    if (exp == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return num * power(num, exp-1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because, `exp--` firstly uses your value for invoking power() function and then gets decremented. In that case, the value passed to the function remains 3. Therefore, it goes into the infinite loop.

You should use either `--exp` or `exp-1`.

Comment: @Zolte you can read more about these operators [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/33-incrementdecrement-operators-and-side-effects/)

Answer (score 0):

You need `--exp`, not `exp--`. `exp--` is post-decrement, meaning that it will only be executed *after* the function call. So, `exp--` is not equivalent to `exp-1` in your code, but `--exp` is: the value will be decremented first, and then the function will be called with the decremented value.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I have to use exp-1?

You could also pre-increment `--exp` which gives you the incremented value.

Post-increment `exp--` takes current value and decrements afterwards.
In your case that *never* changes the value.

You take current the value of `exp` and you're passing it by *value* to function.